# Timestamp using Checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a possible way to create a time-in and time-out every time the checkbox is checked?

[image: Spreadsheet Format]

What I want is when I check the box in column A, a timestamp will appear in the column C format should be like this "HH:00:00". Same goes with the column B and D.

The column E contains the duration for the column C and D.

I've tried searching for answers but I can't find one.